# Referencing psuedo parameters in IF condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to be able to create a condition that would be `True` IFF the current ${AWS::Partition} pseudo variable is `aws-cn`.

I found no reference for this in AWS CloudFormation docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make that condition in the following way:

```
Conditions:
  AWSCN: !Equals 
    - !Sub '${AWS::Partition}'
    - 'aws-cn'
```

And then use it in an IF condition as such:

```
!If 
- AWSCN
- #TRUE
- #FALSE
```